# Angularjs Karma Unit Test - $locale recreated

Tags: angularjs, locale, karma-mocha

we are using karma and mocha for unit-testing in angularjs. But we are having problems with testing our $locale stuff, like formats of dates.

We have three test, is the $locale recreated for each test or not ? And if i use services in those test, are my services also reset or is it possible that test 1 affects test 2 because my service contained some data ?

Here a code snippet:

```
it 'should format currency in german', ->
  inject (localizer, $filter) ->
    localizer 'de'
    expect($filter('currency') 5125, '€').to.be.equal '5.125,00 €'
    expect($filter('currency') 5, '€').to.be.equal '5,00 €'
    expect($filter('currency') .51, '€').to.be.equal '0,51 €'
    expect($filter('currency') 0.515, '€').to.be.equal '0,52 €'

it 'should format date in german', ->
  inject (localizer, $filter) ->
    localizer 'de'
    myDate = new Date 2015,5,22
    expect($filter('date') myDate,'shortDate').to.be.equal '22.06.15'

  app.service 'localizer', ($locale, locales) -> (currentLocale) ->
    console.log("Seting currentLocale to:"+currentLocale+"| lastLocale:"+lastLocale)
    if currentLocale isnt lastLocale
      console.log("currentLocale is now:"+currentLocale)
      lastLocale = currentLocale
      localeData = locales[currentLocale]
      angular.extend $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS, localeData.DATETIME_FORMATS
      angular.extend $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS, localeData.NUMBER_FORMATS
```

The problem is, if after a test with 'de' is again a test with 'de' in the $locale are the english formating values. If i put a localizer 'tr' before the second localizer 'de' it works. Why are the values of $locae are changing? Is it possible to A) prevent $locale from changing or B) to reset my service before each test.

Comment: Please give an example of your code.

Comment: It depends on how you inject the services into your tests.  It is very possible for one test to influence another, but you can also write your tests and testing setup in a way that prevents this.

Comment: Hi,

I also suspect some wrong handling of object references that lead to unexpected results and vary dependeing on the order of the test cases.

Can you please show the code of localizer service?

Greetings!